# Make 2 images float to the right and directly under each other

Tags: css, image, html, css-float

I can't seem to make 2 images float to the right but directly underneath each other. I tried to put them in separate divs then float them but nothing happened what else can I try?

here is what I did:

```
    <div id="div1">
        <img src="img1.png">
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <img src="img2.png">
    </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
    #div1 {

    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #div2 {

    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need the float for something else, change your **CSS** to:

```
#div1, #div2 {
    text-align:right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**EDIT:**
As per your comment, the images are in a container with text.

Here is a solution for such case: http://jsfiddle.net/PNxRZ/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-container">
    <img src="img1.png">
    <img src="img2.png">
Lorem ipsum ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-container img {
    float:right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: thank you this also worked but I don't want my text on the left to get pushed down

Comment: I think I see what you need. Have a loot at my updated answer.

Comment: Worked for me thank you! I had 2 seperate 'div' entries and just combined them into one.

Answer (score 4):

add a div.clearfix between your 2 divs

```
<div id="div1">
    <img src="img1.png">
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="div2">
    <img src="img2.png">
</div>
```

its style should be:

```
.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked, however my content that was on the left side has now been pushed down. what can I do to put it back up?

Comment: you need clear:right; in that case insteed of clear:both; and actually you don't need to create a new div for clearing, it's enought if you put it for #div2 div.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i'd do:

html:

```
<div id="div1">
        <div>
        <img src="img1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
        <img src="img2.jpg">
        </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#div1 { width: 100%;display:block;}
#div1 div { width:100%;height:auto;display:block;clear:both;}
#div1 div img {display:block;float: right;}
```